# How can i dynamically build links using jquery and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a web API which return the following JSOn :-

```
{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/00vf/img?imgid=1', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/vf/img?imgid=2', 'desc': 'sedonddoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/vf/img?imgid=3', 'desc': 'thirddoc'}
```

So i need to build `<a>` links based on the returned JSON , i tried to write the following jquery but it did not work out:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:1431/home/statisjson",
  {

    datetype: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      $("<a/>").attr("href", val.url).appendTo("#links");

    });
  });
})
</script>
<div id="links"></div>
```

and still i need to add the  'desc' JSON object to be the link text, which i can not figure out how to do it?

BR

**::UPDATE::**
I have updated my script to the following but it did not work:-

```
@section scripts {
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {



         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: 'http://localhost:1431/Home/statisjson',
             dataType: "JSON",

             success: function (result) {

                 $.each(result, function (key, val) {


                     $("<a>", { href: val.url, text: val.desc }).appendTo("#links");


                 });
             }
         });


     });

 </script>
```

and the asp.net method which returned JSON looks like:-

```
public ActionResult statisjson(int start = 0, int rows = 50)
        {
 var j = "[{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/img?imgid=1', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/img?imgid=2', 'desc': 'sedonddoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/img?imgid=3', 'desc': 'thirddoc'}]"; 
return Content(j, "application/json");

        }
```

Comment: `$("<a/>").attr("href", val.url).text(val.desc).appendTo("#links");`

Comment: It's not `datetype`, it's `dataType`!

Answer (score 5):

When passing HTML as the first argument, you can pass an object literal containing your properties as the second argument:

```
$("<a>", { href: val.url, text: val.desc }).appendTo("#links");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$("<a>" + val.desc + "</a>").attr("href", val.url).appendTo("#links");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON. You need to add `[]`.

```
[{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/00vf/img?imgid=1', 'desc': 'firstdoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/vf/img?imgid=2', 'desc': 'sedonddoc'},{'url': 'http://192.168.10.50/WCF/vf/img?imgid=3', 'desc': 'thirddoc'}]
```

And you should try this to create your link :

```
$("<a/>").attr("href", val.url).text(val.desc).appendTo("#links");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, see my update, i modify the returned JSON format